# Calling for Free Online Data for Paediatric ECG?

Tags: cardiology, database

I need free online data about heart murmurs to study these:

> heart murmur frequency , S2 heart sound frequency and its split,
>   murmur timing, and duration, murmur intensity, S3 sound presence and
>   intensity, S1 presence and intensity, presence of ejection sounds and
>   arrhythmias

I will cite your source then if I can use your data freely.

I would really have the same data as used in this paper:

> Heart energy signature spectrogram for cardiovascular diagnosis
>   Vladimir Kudriavtsev, Vladimir Polyshchuk and Douglas L Roy

No pediatric ECG data here

- [beecardio](http://www.beecardia.com/physiobank/database/ptbdb?locale=en&page=2) (aggregation of many ECG databases)

**Does anyone have simple data for my task?**

I remember that some CD of some book has some standardised nicely organised sounds that you can use freely.

Comment: Where does ECG come into this?  It seems like a question about auscultation.  What sort of data are you actually looking for?

Comment: Normalised and well measured. This type of data: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/62073194/bmt-2012-4075.pdf They do not share their data publicly. I have asked for the data, but they have ignored my request and do not want to share it.

Answer (score 5):

I recognize this was asked like 7 months ago, but in case you're still looking for a good resource:

I used a CD of heart sounds that is called something like "Harvey Heart Sounds," which I got with the purchase of my stethoscope.  If you can find a copy of this, I found it an excellent tool when training to recognize the differences.

These are good heart sounds: http://depts.washington.edu/physdx/heart/demo.html

If you were looking for something other than the sounds themselves, then I'm not sure if you're asking about.  There are all sorts of good ECG references, especially Dale Dubin's EKG Interpretation book.  And Kablunde was the cardio textbook I used, which I liked.

Comment: Thank you for your good answer! It is never too late. This is a research topic. I need so clean sounds as possible and preferably many so I can then compare and contrast and decide which one is the most cleanest.

Comment: Hmm. I am not sure if these sounds are pediatric. Do you know who has recorded them? Any confirmation about how old the patient has been? I am thinking about the normal heart sound.